# Is it possible to configure a Jenkins Build Job to pick maven artifacts from local maven repository

Tags: maven, build, jenkins, nexus

Is it possible in someway to configure my build job such that rather than picking maven artifacts from the central repo , it picks them from the local maven repo. residing on my system?

NOTE - I want others to be able to run build jobs via jenkins , while pointing to my fusion repo.

Thanks

Comment: Use a repository manager and don't install a Jenkins on users machine.

Comment: I meant users others on the network should be able to  run build jobs..:)

Comment: Binary repository manager is the solution. There is a good refcard on DZone about it: http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/binary-repository-management

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to share a maven repository with multiple users I recommend to use a repository manager see [maven repository management](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html). The mostly used once are [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) and [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/). This can handle the central repo as well as own managed repositories by ThirdParties or by your self. They also work as proxy to reduce the bandwidth used in your organisation.

Comment: I want others on my network to be able to access my repo as well :-|

Comment: You want other hosts to access your .m2 folder on your system? And I am not understanding "run build jobs via jenkins on their own machines " via a Jenkins slave? Maybe it helps if you describe your build job and what he needs to access and where he runs and how others should interact with it. Probably you need something like Nexus or Artifactory.

Comment: You want other hosts to access your .m2 folder on your system? -> EXACTLY!

Comment: Thats a bad idea. Instead deploy everything you want to expose onto the repository manager and let everybody else access that. Exposing your local repository will not scale and have terrible performance and concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

Much easier method to achieve local-only maven builds.

Just use the offline flag (-o):

```
mvn -o clean package
```

Maven will build off your local repo directly and will not pull down updates.